# C++ Functor Syntax

Tags: c++, function-pointers, functor, function-object

I have a question regarding the syntax of how to call a functor in C++. In the code below, why do the first 2 examples work whilst the 3rd and 4th attempt do not?

Also I can call `ob (100);` and it will output `300`, but why can't I call `Class(100)` and have it output `300`? Is there any way to use the overloaded operator `()` without instantiating a new object?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std; 


struct Class
{ 
    void operator() (int a) 
    { 
        cout << a * 3 << " "; 
    } 
} ob; 


int main() 
{ 

    int arr[5] = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 3 }; 

    cout << "Multiple of 3 of elements are : "; 
    for_each(arr, arr + 5, Class());
    cout << endl; 
    for_each(arr, arr + 5, ob); 
    cout << endl; 

    // Why do these not work???
    for_each(arr, arr + 5, Class);
    for_each(arr, arr + 5, ob());

}
```

Comment: `whilst the 3rd and 4th attempt do not` -- You should specify what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: Also [does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/504f77bb5f574bcd)

Comment: `Class` is a type and `ob` is an object. `Class()` is an object and `ob()` is invalid.

Answer (score 7):

`std::for_each`, like many tools in the `<algorithms>` library, expects *something* like a function to be passed. Let's look at its [signature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each):

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction >
UnaryFunction for_each( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f );
```

The type `UnaryFunction` is expected to be *something* that you can pass by value `f`, and which you can call like a function, as in `f(value);`

There are a couple things that satisfy this:

- Function pointers
- Functor objects, which are instances of a class that overloads `operator()`
- Lambdas (which are really just functor objects)

With that in mind, let's look at your example.

---

```
for_each(arr, arr + 5, Class());
```

Here, `Class()` is constructing an instance of class, and `UnaryFunction` is deduced to be `Class`. This is an instance of a class overloading `operator()`, so this is perfectly fine.

---

```
for_each(arr, arr + 5, ob);
```

Here, `ob` is an instance of `Class`, and since it's passed by value, this has the same effect as passing `Class()`.

---

```
for_each(arr, arr + 5, Class);
```

Here, you're trying to pass a *type*, where a value is expected. This very simply is a no-no.

---

```
for_each(arr, arr + 5, ob());
```

Here, you are *calling* `operator()` on the object `ob`. This is bad for two reasons. 1; because `Class::operator()` expects a single `int` as a parameter, and this is missing. 2; because this will attempt to pass the value returned by `operator()` to `for_each`. Since you've defined `Class::operator()` to return `void`, this also makes no sense.